# How to return an image not from a file (content-type image/jpg) trough an cgi-script in python3

Tags: python-3.x, apache, camera, raspberry-pi, cgi

I have a Raspberry pi 3 with a cam and try to return the image it takes trough an cgi-script.

It works with the temperature. I return the html header, the head and body and get the temperature from

```
print (subprocess.run(['vcgencmd', ' measure_temp'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```

without the "decode('utf-8')" it works in the terminal (printing the website to the terminal), but i need to decode it to return it as a website.

for the image i don't know how i should do that.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import subprocess

print( "Content-type:image/jpeg\r\n\r\n")

print (subprocess.run(['raspistill','-o','-']))
```

gives me an output in the terminal, that looks like it could be what i want, but if i open it in the browser i get a broken-image-symbol

Edit:

Okay, the output i get may not be a valid image

```
00000000: ffd8 ffe1 641e 4578 6966 0000 4d4d 002a  ....d.Exif..MM.*
00000010: 0000 0008 000a 0100 0004 0000 0001 0000  ................
00000020: 0a20 0101 0004 0000 0001 0000 0798 010f  . ..............
00000030: 0002 0000 000c 0000 0086 0110 0002 0000  ................
00000040: 000a 0000 0092 011a 0005 0000 0001 0000  ................
00000050: 009c 011b 0005 0000 0001 0000 00a4 0128  ...............(
00000060: 0003 0000 0001 0002 0000 0132 0002 0000  ...........2....
00000070: 0014 0000 00ac 0213 0003 0000 0001 0001  ................
00000080: 0000 8769 0004 0000 0001 0000 00c0 0000  ...i............
00000090: 03a0 5261 7370 6265 7272 7950 6900 5250  ..RaspberryPi.RP
000000a0: 5f6f 7635 3634 3700 0000 0048 0000 0001  _ov5647....H....
000000b0: 0000 0048 0000 0001 3230 3138 3a30 333a  ...H....2018:03:
000000c0: 3234 2031 383a 3232 3a32 3700 0017 829a  24 18:22:27.....
000000d0: 0005 0000 0001 0000 01da 829d 0005 0000  ................
000000e0: 0001 0000 01e2 8822 0003 0000 0001 0003  ......."........
000000f0: 0000 8827 0003 0000 0001 01f4 0000 9000  ...'............
00000100: 0007 0000 0004 3032 3230 9003 0002 0000  ......0220......
00000110: 0014 0000 01ea 9004 0002 0000 0014 0000  ................
00000120: 01fe 9101 0007 0000 0004 0102 0300 9201  ................
00000130: 000a 0000 0001 0000 0212 9202 0005 0000  ................
00000140: 0001 0000 021a 9203 000a 0000 0001 0000  ................
00000150: 0222 9205 0005 0000 0001 0000 022a 9207  ."...........*..
00000160: 0003 0000 0001 0002 0000 9209 0003 0000  ................
00000170: 0001 0000 0000 920a 0005 0000 0001 0000  ................
00000180: 0232 927c 0007 0000 0154 0000 023a a000  .2.|.....T...:..
00000190: 0007 0000 0004 3031 3030 a001 0003 0000  ......0100......
000001a0: 0001 0001 0000 a002 0004 0000 0001 0000  ................
000001b0: 0a20 a003 0004 0000 0001 0000 0798 a005  . ..............
000001c0: 0004 0000 0001 0000 038e a402 0003 0000  ................    
000001d0: 0001 0000 0000 a403 0003 0000 0001 0000  ................
```

Comment: Try running the script in Terminal and redirecting the output to a file. Then run `xxd thatFile` and paste the first few lines into your question by clicking `edit` underneath your question.

Comment: done, now i would say that output doesn't look like an image.

Comment: If i do the same with the command that takes the Foto "raspistill -o -" then i get the exact same first lines. So my html header i print beforehand doesn't get printet? doesn't seem to make sense?!

Comment: The output you get is in byte-like object, and looks like a valid jpeg file, image for web display is using base64 encoding and decoding. You didn't provide information on how exactly you serve the content to html, so i can't help on specific, but take a look at Python [base64](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) library.

Comment: as you can see in my secon code block, the way the apache is supposed to deliver the image is by the html header for images followed by the image itself, as i thought it should be. I may be wrong here.
i wanted to open that script in the image tag of a html document. So the html have an image tag with the script as the source og that image